# Python Grok Learning exception of type IndexError

Tags: python

I just started learning python a few days ago and I have been using Grok Learning. For the challenge I have everything working as far as i can see but when i submit it i am told "Testing yet another case that starts with a vowel. Your submission raised an exception of type IndexError. This occurred on line 8 of your submission." I am not sure how to solve this or even what i am doing wrong. By the way i am making a program to check if the message starts with a vowel and if so times the first letter by 10 if not then times the second letter by 10.

```
msg = input("Enter a word: ")
h = " "
half =" "
first = msg[0]
second = msg[1]
msg2 = "gg"
length = len(msg)
third = msg[2]
if first not in "aeiou":
  if second != third:
    print(msg.replace(msg[1], msg[1] * 10))
  elif second == third:
    msg2 = third * 6
    msg3 = (msg.replace(msg[2], msg2))
    msg4 = first + msg3[2:]
    print(msg4)
else:
  half = first * 10
  msg10 = msg[1:length]
      print((half) + msg10)
```

Comment: It looks like `third = msg[2]` is the problem. `msg` does not contain 3 items so `msg[2]` raises an `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

**You have recieved only two letters string as input** which means you cannot access `msg[2]` because there are no such index.  To handle that case you can define third value as next:

```
if len(msg) > 2:
    third = msg[2]
else:
    third = None
```

Or use one liner:

```
third = msg[2] if len(msg) > 2 else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this probably means the entered message has a length less than 3.
You should check if the message is long enough before trying to access it's content, otherwise you'll indeed get an `IndexError`

```
length = len(msg)
if length > 2:
    third = msg[2]
```